# Is there a way to only show one shape and hide the previous one depending on which shape the user clicks on?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on an application at the moment and I'm on a part where each circle represents a colored circle shape. That shape circle with the color has to show at the end of the application depending on what the user clicks. Is there a way to show one shape but not the others and then show the next shape but not the previous one?

Here is the code to demonstrate this below

```
<p id="circleshapeonesmall"></p>

<p id="circleshapeonenextpart"></p>

#circleshapeonesmall{
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 400px;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-color: #ffcc00;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#circleshapeonenextpart{
position: absolute;
top: 650px;
left: 66px;
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
background-color: #ffcc00;
border-radius: 15px;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#circleshapeonesmall').show();
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#circleshapeonesmall').hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#circleshapeonenextpart').show();
});

<p id="myleast"></p>

    <p id="myleasttext">My Least</p>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#happy').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#ffcc00');
});

});
```

Comment: Could you provide some actual html and script, and explain which concrete image you want to show, and when?

Comment: You need to include just enough code to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remove that comment and edit your question

Comment: This is not clear. There is no button, no click handler. No explanation of the logic that should determine which image to show. If you want a solution that fits your needs, we would need more precise information.

Comment: ok so the basic logic Is if a user clicked on the happy mood and after they clicked on the my least part then that color will appear on the next page. each mood represents a color which is then transformed into a circled shape at the end. does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, no, not to me at least. Have no idea what you are after.